# How to backup my mongoDB documents?

Tags: mongodb

How Can I backup my mongoDB's documents to my hard disk, just to keep my data safe, such that I can use them in near future to reset my database ?

Comment: This isn't really how to use a Document Database.  You might want to look into how databases work (esp MongoDB for this case)  MongoDB's data store is stored on your storage drive (depending on how it was configured).  You can backup the location of the data store of MongoDB to another location, but you aren't going to be able to back up individual BSON objects

Comment: Yes, How to backup the files in MongoDB ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoDump](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongodump/). I used it to export my database to a separate server and it can also be used to take backups, otherwise to safely store data on remote servers look up [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) or [replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/).

Further reading: [backup strategies](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/administration/backups/).